# Matlab impyramid issue

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a problem in impyramid with matlab. I am trying to save one downscale version of a binary image and also a two downscaled version of this binary image. It is simple to do that in matlab as the following code shows:

```
scale1_2= impyramid(compressed_image, 'reduce');
scale1_4= impyramid(scale1_2, 'reduce');
```

So, an image with size 810x1080 is saved with 405x540 and 203x270 pixels. The problem I am facing is when I try to expand these two images back to have the same dimensions as before.

```
scaled_result1_2=impyramid(scale1_2,'expand');
scaled_result1_4=impyramid(impyramid(scale1_4,'expand'), 'expand');
```

So, it is expected that scaled_result1_2 and scaled_result1_4 are 810x1080 images again, but not:

```
>>size(scaled_result1_2)
     809        1079
>>size(scaled_result1_4)
     809        1077
```

I need these two images to have the same 810x1080 pixels again, but impyramid is not able to do this. If I resize these images with imresize will it perform the image pyramid decomposition by upscaling and blurring the image? which method (interpolation) should I have to use to have a similar result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you actually open up `impyramid` and see the source code, it boils down to an `imresize` call.  Specifically, this is what happens when you use `expand` when calling `impyramid` when `A` is defined as the image:

```
M = size(A,1);
N = size(A,2);
scaleFactor = 2;
outputSize = 2*[M N] - 1;
kernel = makePiecewiseConstantFunction( ...
    [1.25   0.75    0.25   -0.25   -0.75   -1.25   -Inf], ...
    [0.0    0.125   0.5     0.75    0.5    0.125    0.0]);
kernelWidth = 3;

B = imresize(A, scaleFactor, {kernel, kernelWidth}, ...
    'OutputSize', outputSize, 'Antialiasing', false);
```

As you can see, `outputSize` is defined as twice the image dimensions subtract 1, which is why you are off by 1 pixel per dimension.  The function `makePiecewiseConstantFunction` is a local function that is defined in `impyramid`.  I'll let you open it up and see that for yourself.  Make sure this is defined before calling the above code.

Therefore, simply remove the subtraction of 1 to achieve what you want.

As such, call the above code, but change `outputSize` to:

```
outputSize = 2*[M N];
```

---

However, if you want to be adventurous, you can modify this source code yourself to take in a flag where if you set it to `true`, it won't subtract by 1 and `false` performs the subtraction.  Therefore, you can modify the header of `impyramid` to do this:

```
function B = impyramid(A, direction, padding)
```

Then, at the beginning before any computation is done, you can do this:

```
if nargin == 2
    padding = false;
end
```

This allows you to call `impyramid` without a third argument, which will default to no padding.

Once you're done, in the `expand` section of the `if` statement, you can do:

```
else
    scaleFactor = 2;
    outputSize = 2*[M N];
    if ~padding %// Change
        outputSize = outputSize - 1;
    end
    kernel = makePiecewiseConstantFunction( ...
        [1.25   0.75    0.25   -0.25   -0.75   -1.25   -Inf], ...
        [0.0    0.125   0.5     0.75    0.5    0.125    0.0]);
    kernelWidth = 3;
end
```

The nested `if` statement then checks to see whether or not you want to allow the output image to be of size `2M x 2N` or `2M - 1 x 2N - 1`.  As such, when you're done modifying the code, you can do:

```
scaled_result1_2 = impyramid(scale1_2, 'expand', true);
scaled_result1_4 = impyramid(impyramid(scale1_4,'expand', true), 'expand', true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But, can I expand the images back to the original size by using imresize? is the effect the same or should I have to use a different kernel to do the interpolation? or the effect is not the same?

Comment: You can use imresize yes. That's what the expand option boils down to but you need to make sure you use the correct interpolation kernel. Read the answer again.